# Change the css class of an element in a Django form that uses ModelForm

Tags: css, django, django-crispy-forms

I have the following model:

```
class PledgeSettings(models.Model):

    message = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    amount = MoneyField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        default_currency='CAD',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

and I have the following form that uses that model:

```
class PledgeSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PledgeSettings

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PledgeSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['message'].widget.attrs = {
            'placeholder': _('Everytime I eat a doughnut'),
        }
        self.fields['message'].label = False

        self.fields['amount'].label = _('I pledge to donate $')

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-xs-9'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-xs-3'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'message',
            'amount'
        )

        self.helper.layout.append(
            Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='save_button')
        )
```

The problem is that `self.helper.label_class = 'col-xs-9'` and `self.helper.field_class = 'col-xs-3'` has no effect, and I would like to set the css class of a particular element, e.g., `message` or `amount`, and

The HTML I am getting is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post"> <input type="hidden" ...>
    <div id="div_id_message" class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="message" value="I smoke a cigarette" placeholder="Some text" class="textinput textInput" id="id_message">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_amount" class="control-group">
        <label for="id_amount_0" class="control-label ">
            Some text
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="number" name="amount_0" value="1.00" step="0.01" class="col-xs-3" id="id_amount_0">

            <select name="amount_1" class="col-xs-3" id="id_amount_1"> 
            <option value="CAD" selected="">Canadian Dollar</option>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I want to change is the classes for the label element and the input element particularly for each element.
I have no idea how to do that. Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you considered Javascript? Or is that out of the question?

Comment: @almostabeginner, yeah I have thought about JS, but I would like to know if you can do it directly in the django form or using the `self.helper` instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like this

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Div(
        Field('message'), css_class="class-here"
    ),

    # Field('description'), # or this way if you don't want to wrap around div
)
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to change the class of the elements I have not to add new elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with crispy-forms, so this can be wrong, but try the following:

For the first issue try `self.helper = FormHelper(self)` instead of `self.helper = FormHelper()`

To set the css class of a particular element, you would need to create a `Layout` like:

> ```
> self.helper.layout = Layout(
>     Field('password', id="password-field", css_class="passwordfields",        
>           title="Explanation")
> )
> ```

[Read more here](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html)

Comment: the problem is that I want to change the class of `self.fields['message']`, not create a new element. The elements I want to use are in my model.

Comment: Does this work? `self.fields['message'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'class-here',
        }`

Comment: sort of work, it changes the class of an input and a select inside a div that is inside a div which holds that also holds a label.